# Question about git shell command to push to multiple remotes

Tags: git

I need help to create a shell command to push to multiple remotes.

In my case I need to push the same code to two different heroku repos and one GitHub repo.

These are the remotes set up currently in the project:

```
git remote -v 
backend https://github.com/my_repo/backend.git (fetch)
backend https://github.com/my_repo/backend.git (push)
generic https://git.heroku.com/generic-backend.git (fetch)
generic https://git.heroku.com/generic-backend.git (push)
origin  https://git.heroku.com/it-backend.git (fetch)
origin  https://git.heroku.com/it-backendo.git (push)
```

I have created a shell file in my home directory and set the permissions to that file.

This is the current content of that file:

```
echo "What is the commit message?" 
read commitMessage cd GitHub/project/backend 
git add . 
git commit -am commitMessage 
git push heroku master
```

Do I need to change the setup of the current git remotes and what in my shell code do I need to change to use one push to all to all the three repos?

Comment: Why not just `git push backend master && git push generic master && git push heroku master` ???

Comment: Git alias [`remotes-push`](https://github.com/GitAlias/gitalias/blob/def8c3e8202ad482010137c20dd8f8fc727bac86/gitalias.txt#L1430) pushes to all remotes (full disclosure: I am a contributor for the repo). Can be used with references: `git remotes-push master`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem with the script (assuming the lack of a newline between `commitMessage` and `cd` is a typo) is that you don't have a remote named `heroku`. Replace the last line with

```
for remote in backend generic origin; do
  git push "$remote" master
done
```

You just need to repeat the `git push` command for the three remotes that *are* defined.

Comment: sorry, some typos when I copy/pasted. the remote named Heroku comes from that if I create a heroku repo called it-backend, then I need to write git push heroku master
So if I understand you correctly the loop will repeat the git push command for all three remotes?

Comment: No, if you called the remote `it-backend`, that's the remote you push to. The fact that "heroku" appears in the URL(s) associated with that remote is irrelevant.

Comment: When I tested the script it seems that my variable commitMessage doesn't read the input I inserted in the terminal after the echo command, but uses the string commitMessage as commit message, what did I do wrong there?

Comment: You passed the literal sting `commitMesage`, not the expansion of the parameter named `commitMessage`: `git commit -am "$commitMessage"`. That said, I wouldn't bother with `read`. Let `git commit` open the user's preferred editor to create the message.

Comment: thanks.. I thought of that.. it was never in put in a variable :)